# subtract two rows and keep the latest row with the same ID in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query where i need to remove or subtract two rows and keep the latest chargeID for the same patid initially i used in my where condtion 
e.g

```
 where transactiontype!=void and transactiontype='charges'.
```

I need to keep the latest 'charges' row.
below is the table [image: table name tranMaster]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Please show sample input, output, and then explain how you get from point a to point b.

Comment: Can you please show the output you want. From your question, it seems that a simple rank function would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ranking function with partition by patid and order by chargeid DESC then filter out unnecessary records from where clause.

Comment: it worked ,but i have one problem i have two transactiontype such as 'CHARGES' From there i need to select only one chargeID having the latest date

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this 

DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    PatId INT,
    ChargeId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TranType VARCHAR(20),
    SomeText VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @T
(
    PatId,
    TranType,
    SomeText
)
VALUES(598,'Void','Sample 11'),
    (598,'Charges','Sample 12'),
    (598,'Charges','Sample 13'),
    (611,'Void','Sample 21'),
    (611,'Void','Sample 22'),
    (611,'Charges','Sample 23')

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PatId,TranType ORDER BY ChargeId DESC),
       *
       FROM @T
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
       WHERE RN = 1
```

Sample Input

[image]

Sample Output

[image]